# Does this violate good Unit Testing patterns?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a little class called `Enforce` that does... well argument enforcement.

```
public static class Enforce
{
    public static void ArgumentNotNull<T>(T parameter, string parameterName)
    {
        CheckParameterName(parameterName);

        if (parameter.IsNull())
            throw new ArgumentNullException(parameterName);
    }

    // Edited for briveity

    private static void CheckParameterName(string parameterName)
    {
        if (parameterName.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
            throw new ArgumentNullException("parameterName");
    }
}
```

I was just wondering if using this inside of constructors creates an unacceptable dependency:

```
public ControllerBase(TValidatingService service, IModelStateWrapperFactory modelStateWrapperFactory)
    {
        Enforce.ArgumentNotNull(service, "service");

        // Or should I be doing it like this?
        if (service == null)
            throw new System.ArgumentNullException("service");

        this.Service = service;
    }
```

Comment: I agree with @NedStoyanov's answer. I just wanted to mention that the `IsNull` check is unnecessary, following `CheckParameterName`, since the latter covers that scenario with `IsNullOrWhitespace`.

Comment: @Lilshieste - `ChackParameterName` checks the `parameterName` while the `IsNull()` checks the actual `parameter` value.

Comment: Ack! Completely missed that; sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it creates an unnecessary dependency, however you are reinventing the wheel a little bit as there are already existing design by contract APIs such as [Code Contracts](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/) by Microsoft